# java INSERT query doesn't work (java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java-7

When I run this code I get an null pointer Exception.

```
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO viwa(name,tele,surname) VALUES(?,?,?)";
         pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, jTextField_name.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField_age.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField_tele.getText());

        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

****This's the full code****

> `   import java.sql.Connection;    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
>   import java.sql.ResultSet; import java.sql.Statement; import
>   javax.swing.JOptionPane;
>
> public class go extends javax.swing.JFrame {
>
> ```
> Connection conn = null;
> ResultSet rs = null;   PreparedStatement pst = null;
>
>
> public go() {
>     try {
>         initComponents();
>         connect.getMyConn();
>
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
>
>
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
>  // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated    Code">                          
> private void initComponents() {
>
>     jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jTextField_Tele = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>     jTextField_Surname = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>     jTextField_Name = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>     jButton_search = new javax.swing.JButton();
>     jButton_Update = new javax.swing.JButton();
>     jButton_Delete = new javax.swing.JButton();
>     jButton_save = new javax.swing.JButton();
>
>     setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
>     getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
>
>     jLabel1.setText("Tele");
>     getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 140, -1, -1));
>
>     jLabel2.setText("Surname");
>     getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 210, -1, -1));
>
>     jLabel3.setText("Name");
>     getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 70, -1, -1));
>
>     jTextField_Tele.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jTextField_TeleActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>     getContentPane().add(jTextField_Tele, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 140, 170, -1));
>     getContentPane().add(jTextField_Surname, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 210, 170, -1));
>     getContentPane().add(jTextField_Name, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 70, 170, -1));
>
>     jButton_search.setText("Search");
>     getContentPane().add(jButton_search, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 310, 120, -1));
>
>     jButton_Update.setText("Update");
>     getContentPane().add(jButton_Update, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(390, 310, 120, -1));
>
>     jButton_Delete.setText("Delete");
>     getContentPane().add(jButton_Delete, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(540, 310, 120, -1));
>
>     jButton_save.setText("Save");
>     jButton_save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
>         public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
>             jButton_saveActionPerformed(evt);
>         }
>     });
>     getContentPane().add(jButton_save, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(90, 310, 120, -1));
>
>     pack();
> }// </editor-fold>                        
>
> private void jTextField_TeleActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
>
>     // TODO add your handling code here:
> }                                               
>
> private void jButton_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
>
>     try {
>
>         String sql = "INSERT INTO viwa (name,tele,surname) VALUES(?,?,?)";
>        pst =  conn.prepareStatement(sql);
>
>         pst.setString(1, jTextField_Name.getText());
>         pst.setString(2, jTextField_Tele.getText());
>         pst.setString(3, jTextField_Surname.getText());
>
>         pst.execute();
>
>         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>
> }      `
> ```

Comment: On which line you are getting null pointer exception? Is your connection variable `conn` is initialized prior calling `prepareStatement()` method on it i.e `pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);`

Add full code snippet for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Using your IDE, put a breakpoint at the start of this code and step through it watching all variables. One of your variables holds the unexpected `null` value. There is no other obvious reason for NPE in your code.